# redis-sentinel throws error: " Can't resolve master instance hostname."

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-sentinel

I'm starting up redis and sentinel nodes using the below configurations. I start the redis node first and when I start Sentinel, if fails with the error:

```
sentinel_node |
sentinel_node | *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
sentinel_node | Reading the configuration file, at line 1
sentinel_node | >>> 'sentinel monitor MasterRedis redis_node 6000 3'
sentinel_node | Can't resolve master instance hostname.
sentinel_node exited with code 1
```

*Redis Compose*

```
version: '2.1'
services:

redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis_node
    environment:
    - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    ports:
    - 6000:6000
    volumes:
    - ./redis_startup.sh:/usr/local/bin/redis_startup.sh
    - ./redis_server_stop.sh:/usr/local/bin/redis_server_stop.sh
    command: ["redis_startup.sh", "-port", "6000"]
```

*redis_startup.sh*

```
redis-server --port ${port:-6000}
```

*sentinel compose*

```
version: '2.1'
services:

sentinel:
    image: redis
    container_name: sentinel_node
    ports:
    - 26379:26379
    volumes:
    # This is a read-only file on the host disk. It will be
    # used to create a rw file in this image
    - ./sentinel_node.conf:/usr/local/sentinel_node.conf
    - ./sentinel_startup.sh:/usr/local/bin/sentinel_startup.sh
    - ./redis_server_stop.sh:/usr/local/bin/redis_server_stop.sh
    command: ["sentinel_startup.sh", "-port", "6000", "-name", "sentinel_node"]
```

*sentinel startup script*

```
redis-server /etc/sentinel_node.conf --sentinel
```

*sentinel conf*

```
sentinel monitor MatserRedis redis_node 6000 3
sentinel down-after-milliseconds MatserRedis 3000
sentinel failover-timeout MatserRedis 10000
sentinel parallel-syncs MatserRedis 1
```

The redis node starts up without error.

Answer (score 23):

Only sentinel with version above 6.2 can resolve host names, but this is not  enabled by default. Adding `sentinel resolve-hostnames yes` to `sentinel.conf` will help.

If your sentinel has older versions, the hostname `redis_node` should be replaced by and ip.

For more details, check out [IP Addresses and DNS names](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#ip-addresses-and-dns-names) in Redis document

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't enable this and having same issues. now it's working...

Answer (score 4):

With the latest redis version, you simply add "sentinel resolve-hostnames yes" to sentinel.conf. Everything works like a charm.

Ref: https://redis.io/topics/sentinel

Answer (score -3):

I think it's probably because `redis_node` doesn't resolve to an IP address. Perhaps try putting the IP address in sentinel.conf instead.

The spelling of `MatserRedis` in the `sentinel.conf` file looks questionable too.

Answer (score -3):

I think you have to expose the ports, like this:

```
expose:
      - 6379
```

for the redis instance and like this:

```
expose:
      - 26379
```

for the sentinel instance.

More importantly, you have to have the same docker network attached to both compose files!